# Looking for a critique of my current routine

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines

I've been lifting since around March of last year. Starting late August/Early september, I started doing the routine I'll list below. It was off the recommendation of someone I know, so I'm curious as to whether I should switch to something that's more suited to my goals. I'd also like to see if I'm doing too much volume with regards to certain muscles (like my lats), and if I'm neglecting any muscle groups. It's a PPL routine, with a rest day after every 3 days of working out. Im 18 years old, 5'11, and around 145-148 lbs at 11-12 bf%. I'm looking to gain weight cleanly (probably to around 160lbs), and my current workouts usually last an hour to an hour and a half.

**PUSH**

3x12 Bench Press
3x12 DB Fly
3x12 DB Skull Crushers
3x12 Cable Overhead Fly
3x12 Cable Underhand Fly
3x12 Tricep Extension

**PULL**

3x12 Wide Grip Row
3x12 Close Grip Row
3x12 Close Grip Lat Pulldown
3x12 Medium Grip Lat Pulldown
3x12 Wide Grip Lat Pulldown
3x12 DB Incline Curls
3x12 DB Hammer Curls
3x12 DB Rotating Bicep Curl
3x12 Close Grip Barbell Curl
3x12 Abdominal Crunch Machine

**LEGS (and shoulders)**

3x12 Leg Press
3x12 Calf Raises on Leg Press
3x12 Leg Extension
3x12 Hamstring Curls
3x12 Shoulder Press Machine
3x12 DB Press
3x12 DB Flys

Any feedback you have would be really appreciated. I want to make sure I'm getting the most out of my routine, while also being cognizant of the possibility of overworking or underworking any muscle groups.

Comment: Right away - where is squat, deadlift, ohp. Where is your ab work - don't buy into the "you don't need to do abs separately myth".

Comment: @VSO "don't need to do abs separately myth" isn't a myth, it's a "depends". The time spent doing core focused work should be consistent with your overall fitness goals. Core work is, in general, nonspecific to everything except the particular exercises performed, so if core strength is already sufficient for what you are trying to do, dedicated core training is not necessary.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov - I disagree entirely. Skipping crunches, planks, and hip thrusts is giving a bunch of people anterior pelvic tilt. Maybe experts with perfect form on squat and deadlifts are hitting abs, glutes, erector spinae, etc through stabilization; beginners don't have their form down to that degree though. My 2 cents is that telling people to ignore core work and "it gets worked anyway" is extremely harmful. If you don't need ab work, you are definitely at a level where you aren't asking for advice here.

Comment: @VSO You said you disagree, then gave a case study applying what I said. *If* you determine that you have APT, *and* you determine that it is actually a source of pain or immobility, *and* you determine that it is from weak transverse or rectus abdominis, then you have determined that you *do*, in fact, need to be doing dedicated core work,  that your core strength is *insufficient* for doing other fitness related tasks, and that doing dedicated core work *is* necessary for your current fitness goals. I didnt say skip your ab work. I said it's context dependent.

Comment: Fair enough @ThomasMarkov

Comment: I'd use less grip variations on rows and lat pulldowns and just do more sets per session on the remaining exercises. This way you can improve on form and have more options to rotate exercises later, watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ei-38EcxHE4